# get String from Json without OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android, json, out-of-memory

when i try to get string from server with json format, i get error as follows
**java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 68706640 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 37MB until OOM
                                                                        at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:118)**

My java code is as follows

```
JSONArray eventArray = eventResult.getJSONArray("event");
  for (int i=0; i<eventArray.length(); i++){
      final ArrayList<String> divisi = new ArrayList<>();
      final ArrayList<Timeline> timelines = new ArrayList<>();
      JSONObject eventObj = eventArray.getJSONObject(i);
      String namaEvent = eventObj.getString("nama_event");
      String deskripsi = eventObj.getString("deskripsi");
      String tanggal = eventObj.getString("tanggal");
      JSONArray eventArray1 = eventObj.getJSONArray("divisi");
      JSONArray eventArray2 = eventObj.getJSONArray("timeline");
      for (int j=0; j<eventArray1.length(); i++){
         JSONObject eventObj1 = eventArray1.getJSONObject(j);
         String namaDivisi = eventObj1.getString("nama_divisi");
         divisi.add(namaDivisi);
      }

      for (int k=0; k<eventArray2.length(); k++){
        JSONObject eventObj2 = eventArray2.getJSONObject(k);
        String tanggalTimeline = eventObj2.getString("tanggal_timeline");
        String deskripsiTimeline = eventObj2.getString("deskripsi_timeline");
        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(tanggalTimeline, deskripsiTimeline);
        timelines.add(timeline);
        }
  Event event = new Event(namaEvent,deskripsi,tanggal,divisi,timelines);
  events.add(event);
  }
```

and the json structure I will be parsing is

```
{
    "error": false,
    "event": [
        {
            "id_event": "67",
            "nama_event": "Anforcom",
            "deskripsi": "Lomba mobile apps  nasional",
            "tanggal": "2017-10-21",
            "divisi": [
                {
                    "id_divisi": "DI-67-0",
                    "nama_divisi": "keamanan"
                },
                {
                    "id_divisi": "DI-67-1",
                    "nama_divisi": "humas"
                },
                {
                    "id_divisi": "DI-67-2",
                    "nama_divisi": "acara"
                },
                {
                    "id_divisi": "DI-67-3",
                    "nama_divisi": "PDD"
                },
                {
                    "id_divisi": "DI-67-0",
                    "nama_divisi": "keamanan"
                },
                {
                    "id_divisi": "DI-67-1",
                    "nama_divisi": "humas"
                },
                {
                    "id_divisi": "DI-67-2",
                    "nama_divisi": "acara"
                },
                {
                    "id_divisi": "DI-67-3",
                    "nama_divisi": "PDD"
                },
                {
                    "id_divisi": "DI-67-0",
                    "nama_divisi": "keamanan"
                },
                {
                    "id_divisi": "DI-67-1",
                    "nama_divisi": "humas"
                },
                {
                    "id_divisi": "DI-67-2",
                    "nama_divisi": "acara"
                },
                {
                    "id_divisi": "DI-67-3",
                    "nama_divisi": "PDD"
                }
            ],
            "timeline": [
                {
                    "id_timeline": "TL-67-0",
                    "tanggal_timeline": "2017-10-13",
                    "deskripsi_timeline": "Tes wawancara"
                },
                {
                    "id_timeline": "TL-67-0",
                    "tanggal_timeline": "2017-10-13",
                    "deskripsi_timeline": "Tes wawancara"
                },
                {
                    "id_timeline": "TL-67-0",
                    "tanggal_timeline": "2017-10-13",
                    "deskripsi_timeline": "Tes wawancara"
                },
                {
                    "id_timeline": "TL-67-0",
                    "tanggal_timeline": "2017-10-13",
                    "deskripsi_timeline": "Tes wawancara"
                },
                {
                    "id_timeline": "TL-67-1",
                    "tanggal_timeline": "2017-10-14",
                    "deskripsi_timeline": "Hasil tes wawancara"
                },
                {
                    "id_timeline": "TL-67-1",
                    "tanggal_timeline": "2017-10-14",
                    "deskripsi_timeline": "Hasil tes wawancara"
                },
                {
                    "id_timeline": "TL-67-1",
                    "tanggal_timeline": "2017-10-14",
                    "deskripsi_timeline": "Hasil tes wawancara"
                },
                {
                    "id_timeline": "TL-67-1",
                    "tanggal_timeline": "2017-10-14",
                    "deskripsi_timeline": "Hasil tes wawancara"
                },
                {
                    "id_timeline": "TL-67-2",
                    "tanggal_timeline": "2017-10-20",
                    "deskripsi_timeline": "Technical meeting"
                },
                {
                    "id_timeline": "TL-67-2",
                    "tanggal_timeline": "2017-10-20",
                    "deskripsi_timeline": "Technical meeting"
                },
                {
                    "id_timeline": "TL-67-2",
                    "tanggal_timeline": "2017-10-20",
                    "deskripsi_timeline": "Technical meeting"
                },
                {
                    "id_timeline": "TL-67-2",
                    "tanggal_timeline": "2017-10-20",
                    "deskripsi_timeline": "Technical meeting"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id_event": "71",
            "nama_event": "I-Gate",
            "deskripsi": "Gathering antar angkatan mahasiswa informatika",
            "tanggal": "2017-10-28",
            "divisi": [
                {
                    "id_divisi": "DI-71-0",
                    "nama_divisi": "Humas"
                },
                {
                    "id_divisi": "DI-71-1",
                    "nama_divisi": "PDD"
                },
                {
                    "id_divisi": "DI-71-2",
                    "nama_divisi": "Keamanan"
                },
                {
                    "id_divisi": "DI-71-0",
                    "nama_divisi": "Humas"
                },
                {
                    "id_divisi": "DI-71-1",
                    "nama_divisi": "PDD"
                },
                {
                    "id_divisi": "DI-71-2",
                    "nama_divisi": "Keamanan"
                }
            ],
            "timeline": [
                {
                    "id_timeline": "TL-71-0",
                    "tanggal_timeline": "2017-10-21",
                    "deskripsi_timeline": "Pengumuman Tes Wawancara"
                },
                {
                    "id_timeline": "TL-71-0",
                    "tanggal_timeline": "2017-10-21",
                    "deskripsi_timeline": "Pengumuman Tes Wawancara"
                },
                {
                    "id_timeline": "TL-71-0",
                    "tanggal_timeline": "2017-10-21",
                    "deskripsi_timeline": "Pengumuman Tes Wawancara"
                },
                {
                    "id_timeline": "TL-71-1",
                    "tanggal_timeline": "2017-10-20",
                    "deskripsi_timeline": "Tes Wawancara"
                },
                {
                    "id_timeline": "TL-71-1",
                    "tanggal_timeline": "2017-10-20",
                    "deskripsi_timeline": "Tes Wawancara"
                },
                {
                    "id_timeline": "TL-71-1",
                    "tanggal_timeline": "2017-10-20",
                    "deskripsi_timeline": "Tes Wawancara"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id_event": "72",
            "nama_event": "I Care",
            "deskripsi": "I Care",
            "tanggal": "2017-10-20",
            "divisi": [
                {
                    "id_divisi": "DI-72-0",
                    "nama_divisi": "Keamanan"
                },
                {
                    "id_divisi": "DI-72-1",
                    "nama_divisi": "Humas"
                },
                {
                    "id_divisi": "DI-72-0",
                    "nama_divisi": "Keamanan"
                },
                {
                    "id_divisi": "DI-72-1",
                    "nama_divisi": "Humas"
                }
            ],
            "timeline": [
                {
                    "id_timeline": "TL-72-0",
                    "tanggal_timeline": "2017-10-25",
                    "deskripsi_timeline": "Wawancara"
                },
                {
                    "id_timeline": "TL-72-0",
                    "tanggal_timeline": "2017-10-25",
                    "deskripsi_timeline": "Wawancara"
                },
                {
                    "id_timeline": "TL-72-1",
                    "tanggal_timeline": "2017-10-24",
                    "deskripsi_timeline": "Pengumuman"
                },
                {
                    "id_timeline": "TL-72-1",
                    "tanggal_timeline": "2017-10-24",
                    "deskripsi_timeline": "Pengumuman"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

anyone can help?

Comment: If you have large amount of data, please use [JsonReader](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html) which parsees data token-wise. I have used JsonReader to parse 5Mb of data and this worked the best :)

Comment: The VM is trying to allocate 65MB! Are you sure this is only text?

Comment: Have you tried  Gson for json parsing?That will increase the parsing performance

Comment: Yes, this is only text

Comment: The json you provided seems like a small file, it should not be a problem. I have 2 suggestions: Use [Google GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) for parsing, and try to load the json from a local file just to confirm json does not have huge blank spaces or something weird.

Comment: @roihan Is that the full json file or did you remove some rows out because it is too large? As lalongooo said that file you posted shouldn't cause an OOM exception. Also, what is you memory usage prior to running this code? Maybe you are already at the edge of allowed memory for you app and this is pushing the boundaries. Do you have a lot of large images in your app or anything that takes a lot of memory?

Comment: i have not tried gson, can any reference be given to Gson parsing?

Comment: GSON would be good to use as it implicilty usese JOSNReader only. But in order  to implement gson, you will need to make changes in your existing classes. If you are good to make changes then go ahead. Else the most preferable will be *JsonReader*. @roihan

Comment: Yon can follow this [tutorial](https://kylewbanks.com/blog/tutorial-parsing-json-on-android-using-gson-and-volley) for Gson.

Comment: @WadeWilson that is full json file. I have image file with base64 image string format in shared preference, does it affect OOM exception?

Comment: @SweetWisherツ ok, thanks i will try it

Comment: @roihan why have you stored base64 in sharedPref ? If you want to use an image then either save its url or save it locally and store path in SharedPref.

Comment: @roihan First check with the answer given, Is it a typo ?

Comment: @WadeWilson before parsing I have used sqlite to store user data string (name, email and url profile photo) and I use shared preference to store image profile photo with base64 string format, to offline condition

Comment: @roihan View the answer below, it will fix your problem. You have an infinite loop in your code that is causing several strings to be created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it might be this typo?

```
for (int j=0; j<eventArray1.length(); i++){
     JSONObject eventObj1 = eventArray1.getJSONObject(j);
     String namaDivisi = eventObj1.getString("nama_divisi");
     divisi.add(namaDivisi);
  }
```

you're incrementing i instead of j.

Try changing code here :

```
for (int j=0; j<eventArray1.length(); j++)
```

Comment: this can be the case in which you will be in an infinite loop @roihan

Comment: @SweetWisherツ hahh .. thanks a lot, that is the problem